# Vue Error in render: "RangeError: Invalid array length"

Tags: vue.js, v-for

Vue: v2.*

In my project vuejs
I use `v-for` range
with computed

**Computed**

```
computed: {
   numberOfPages() {
         const result = Math.ceil(this.collection.total / this.collection.per_page)
         return (result < 1) ? 1 : result
    }
},
```

**template**

```
<li class="waves-effect" v-for="(number,index) in numberOfPages" 
    :key="index" :class="collection.current_page == number ? 'active' : ''"
     @click="currentPage(number)">
   <a class="">{{number}}</a>
</li>
```

**Error Console**

1 - `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "RangeError: Invalid array length"`

2 - `RangeError: Invalid array length`

Comment: Check your computed property, it could be the calculation.

Comment: v-for expects an array https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for you could calculate number of pages then create an array containing a list with numbers.

Comment: my bad, v-for can handle ranges: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range try v-for="number in numberOfPages" and see if it works

Comment: @Sombriks I just checked and `(number, index) in numberOfPages` works just fine

Comment: I don't see any conceivable way that `Math.ceil(anyPositiveNumber / anyPositiveNumber)` could ever be less-than 1 so your ternary expression is totally redundant. _Ed: unless `total` is `0` I suppose_

Comment: for `v-for="(number,index) in numberOfPages"` when `numberOfPages` is minus, it will pop up above two errors. But numberOfPages will be positive always. Are you sure the error is triggered at this line?

Comment: Thanks guys for replying

Comment: I'm sure for this error but when I change this numperOfpage or return it to far in data it work fine but I should open consloe Vue to show this data I don't know the problem here so all your suggestiona I did try all above....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most likely candidate for your problem is that your computed property returns `NaN` or `Infinity`. Without seeing all of your code, the most likely reason for that is one of the following:

- You initialize `collection` to an empty Object. `const result = Math.ceil(undefined / undefined)` will return `NaN`
- You do correctly prevent the property from being calculated before the result comes in, but the response from the server that populates `collection` has a `per_page` of `0`. The calculation mentioned above would return `Infinity`, and Vue would not be able to create a range from that.

There are multiple ways of dealing with this problem. The easiest way is, if you can be certain that `per_page` is always `> 0`, to put a `v-if` on the element around your loop. If there is no convenient element, you can use the `<template>` element to put around it.

Otherwise you can check in your computed property if de data you are going to calculate with, is actually correct, and otherwise return a default number.

```
numberOfPages() {
  if (
    !this.collection ||
    Number.isNaN(parseInt(this.collection.total)) ||
    Number.isNaN(parseInt(this.collection.per_page)) ||
    this.collection.per_page <= 0
  ) {
    return 0;
  }

  const result = Math.ceil(this.collection.total / this.collection.per_page)
  return (result < 1) ? 1 : result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like someone else said, carefully check your computed properties. I had two different "interesting" situations (bugs that I introduced):

(1) First I forgot to include the "return" keyword in my computed property!
    So I was doing:

````
```
myComputedProp () {
    arr.length
}
```
````

which should have been `return arr.length` ... easy to overlook :-)

(2) Second, the result of my calculation (which I used as an array length/size) was not an integer but a real (broken number). Solution was of course to add `Math.round()` or `Math.trunc()` ... :-)